# We're in a state of [flux] with [reactjs-flux]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

The tag wikis of [flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/flux) and [reactjs-flux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reactjs-flux) suggest they're referring to the same concept. Should they be merged?

Comment: reactjs-flux seems redundant indeed. Question is: will people stop creating it when only flux exists? Maybe making reactjs-flux a synonym is better.